# Regular Expression Repeated Group C#/C++

Tags: .net, regex

I have the following Regex,

```
^([d-])([rwxt-]{3}){3}
```

There are two groups, and the second is repeated 3 times.   When I use Groups[1] off of a Match object, I get the first group, but I only get the last match of the second group with Groups[2].   How do I access all the repeated matches of the second group in .NET?

Thanks,

Bruce

Answer (score 1):

You could use `\G` option and capture only the first 4 matches like so

```
^([d-])|\G([rwxt-]{3})
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/64)

Answer (score 1):

You can't, the .net regex engine doesn't store the three repeated groups, it stores only the last one that overwrites the previous and so on.

You can use @alphabravo pattern with a global research:

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|^([\d-]))([rwxt-]{3})
```

or simply write:

```
^([d-])([rwxt-]{3})([rwxt-]{3})([rwxt-]{3})
```